# Eslint doesn't allow async in onMounted hook of VueJS

Tags: javascript, eslint, typescript-eslint

There is no error in the code It works perfectly fine. But Eslint is not allowing us to use async inside the `onMounted` hook. If I use .then() promise it is allowing. What is wrong here why can't we use async instead of .then() ?? clearly this doesn't return anything

```
onMounted(async() => {
  something.value = await fetchValue();
});
```

esLint Error:

```
error  Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected  @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing what's in you featchValue(), it is difficult to pinpoint the issue.

According to the error throwing from the esLint, the fetchValue() should return a value and right now it's returning void

Comment: the problem here is about the usage of async, and await in onMounted. Inside fetchValue() consider a normal Promise returning the value